# Starting flow free game development

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I'm starting the developpement of a flow free game on android.

I'm a bit confused about the architecture design.

Should I use grids/tablelayout available on android framework or just draw my own objects by specifying the position and which object to draw.

I created classes for each object as : POINT, EMPTY, SQUARE.

I want to create a prototype like on those links :

http://forums.gamesalad.com/discussion/48641/my-flow-free-inspired-game-development-thread

[image: a busy cat]

For the moment, I don't have to design the IA, I just need to focus on the game architecture and physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I use grids/tablelayout available on android framework or just draw my own objects by specifying the position and which object to draw.

You shouldn't use grids/tablelayout.

For 2D games where you need performance, use OpenGL or take a look at the andengine library.

Since this is going to be a simple 2D game, you should look at `Canvas`. Take a look at Android Sample Project > TicTacToeLib and Android Sample Project > TicTacToeMain (you need to use them both toghether). The GameView inside TicTacToeLib shows you how to use Canvas in a game.

What you will see when you compile TicTacToeMain with TicTacToeLib:

[image]

Comment: I don't need OpenGL, it's in 2D.

Comment: OpenGL can be 2d. But, I revised this. You should use canvas.

Comment: Thank you, I will get a look on this exemple! I guess that the canvas can be changed dynamically to draw NxN blocks on the Map?

Comment: You can paint all sorts of things on canvas: squares, circles, lines, curves, and existing images. You should be able to change the existing example by a lot.